# What was the highest rated episode of Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-enterprise

In all of the televised episodes of Star Trek (TOS, TAS, TNG, DS9, VOY & ENT), what was the single highest Nielsen rated episode?

Comment: I have heard "The Trouble with Tribbles" informally mentioned as the most popular episode, but I don't know which metric they used, and the statement might have been biased as it was brought up in an interview with the writer of the episode (David Gerrold?)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The series premiere for **TOS** (The Man Trap) opened with a Nielsen rating of [**25.2**](http://startrekfactcheck.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/the-truth-about-star-trek-and-ratings.html) (albeit facing dramatically less competition than future shows). This is a figure that would never again be matched by any trek episode.

The series premiere **DS9** (Emissary) garnered the largest overall Nielsen rating for a modern show with a score of [18.8](http://web.archive.org/web/20001004073227/http://treknation.com/nielsens/ds9/index.shtml).

The next most popular was the series finale of **TNG** (All Good Things) with a score of [17.4](http://web.archive.org/web/20001005230107/http://treknation.com/nielsens/tng/season7.shtml)

The highest rated episode of **Voyager** was the series premiere (Caretaker) with a score of [13.3](http://web.archive.org/web/20001006024813/http://treknation.com/nielsens/voy/season1.shtml).

The highest rated episode of **Enterprise** (Broken Bow, Part 1) was a limp [9.1](http://mvrojo.tripod.com/entratings.htm), declining to a positively flaccid [2.2](http://mvrojo.tripod.com/entratings.htm) before finally being put out of everyone's misery.

The highest rated episode of **Discovery** thus far (The Vulcan Hello, Part 1) was a frankly appalling [1.9](https://tvbythenumbers.zap2it.com/daily-ratings/tv-ratings-sunday-sept-24-2017/) but this doesn't take into account that the show had already been broadcast on [CBS' own subscription-only service](https://www.cbs.com/shows/star-trek-discovery/).

Comment: Any numbers for the Animated Series?

Comment: Please note that these figures are almost all "unofficial". Nielsen ratings are supposed to be confidential and were restricted to subscribers only. There's also a major differential between what the ratings were looking at over the years; overnights, ratings across markets, syndicated ratings, etc that make it very difficult to compare like with like.

Comment: I think the ratings for TOS  were all included in *These Are The Voyages*,  by episode. Are those "official"?

Comment: @Jonah - I would expect so. Do they tally with the number above?

Comment: "For locating the Nielsen ratings for the original broadcasts of ST:TOS, I am indebted to Kate Barnett at Nielsen Media Services." VERY official.

Comment: @Jonah - Well there you are :-)

Comment: I'd say they are the same. One caveat: 46.7 (percent) is the *share*. The *rating* was 25.2.

Comment: @Jonah - Ah, corrected. Am I still right in saying that it was the highest rated of the whole series?

Comment: The ratings are all spread out, so it was taking me a while to look at them. But probably.

Comment: @sfhq_sf - I can't find any. I gather it had poor ratings but was also **very cheap** to make. To give you some idea how cheap, Roddenberry and his producer ended up commissioning half a dozen episodes with their own money to round off the series.

Comment: "a limp 9.1" ...you smug SOB

Comment: @coburne - It's not a good sign when your show opens below the point at which its predecessor got cancelled

Comment: I'd much rather watch an episode of ***Enterprise*** than ***Voyager***, and I know I'm not the only one.

Comment: @greenmatt - The ratings suggest you'd be the only one watching it though.

Comment: @Richard: There have been suggestions that the viewing public was  tired of Star Trek by the time ***Enterprise*** debuted. Also that ***Voyager***',s failures (I note you didn't include that show's worst ratings) led to disinterest in the franchise, thus suppressing interest in ***Enterprise***. The poor opening for ***Enterprise*** seems to support these ideas.

Comment: @GreenMatt Your tastes may also be "adjusted" by the series you grew up with. For me, Voyager is the great series in the franchise.

Comment: Looks like I've beaten you again in the upvote count here. Wasn't intentional! :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Pretty pictures always score higher points, even if they're filled with material inaccuracies... :-P

Comment: @Richard: I'm going to give this one to you, even though Rand al'Thor's answer scored higher. Your answer was more complete (the ratings for TOS blew me away and was not what I expected). Great answer!!

Comment: @IQAndreas: Or that you didn't grow up with. I was alive when TOS was aired, but too young to appreciate it. Where I grew up, it was rarely available in syndication. When ***ST The Motion Picture*** came out, I had probably read more of James Blish's adaptations of the episodes than I'd watched. By the time TNG came on, I was well past "growing up". That said, I just thought ***Voyager*** was poorly done and ***Enterprise*** was better.

Comment: The ratings for Enterprise failed to take into account things like DVRs/TiVO, which were just starting to be used at that time

Comment: @MatthewBarclay - Even taking into account 7-day ratings, the show was a horrible flop

Answer (score 60):

You can see the Nielsen ratings for **ALL** modern Star Trek episodes (TNG, DS9, VOY, and ENT) plotted together on this handy graph from [here](http://www.madmind.de/2009/05/02/all-star-trek-movies-and-episodes-in-two-charts/):

[image]

Which confirms [Richard's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/126472/31394) (the highest outside of TOS is **the DS9 premiere *Emissary***, followed by **the TNG finale *All Good Things***), but I thought it was worth a separate answer for the complete graph displaying them all so nicely.

Comment: I saw that, but since they weren't labelled by episode, I decided not to. Also, his numbers are a little screwy, at least 1-2 points below the published figures for Voyager and Enterprise. I'm not sure why he's done that but I suspect it's a rounding error since it's across all of his charts.

Comment: I was going to write a long, detailed answer (including this) but you two got there while I was reading *These Are The Voyages*. :)

Comment: @Jonah - There's nothing to stop you. If your answer is superior, it will get more votes and bubble up to the top. I've done as much research as I feel like I need to (to answer the question to my own satisfaction) but that doesn't mean you can't go the extra mile.

Comment: It's interesting how stable the TNG ratings are. Trekkie-craze? Hardly any "sci-fi" alternatives on the market? Just giving you your "daily bread" like Dallas? It's a shame it's not labeled with dates (though we can make some rough guesses).

Comment: @Luaan: The television market exploded in the 1990s, VHS became more commonplace and the internet was hitting homes. The very consistent downward trend that hit the entire franchise is remarkably evident here (so it would be nice if people stopped blaming individual shows without evidence!)

Comment: Most interesting to me:  TNG has a slight wave pattern that coincides with the seasons.  None of the others do.

Comment: In addition to *All Good Things*, the other two high rated *ST:TNG* outliers are *Encounter at Farpoint* and *Unification*. But which are the two low rated episodes for *DS9* and *Voyager* that fall below the trend line?

Comment: It's also interesting that when time spans for *TNG*, *DS9*, and *Voyager* overlapped, the end of one Star Trek series didn't result in a jump in viewers for the other, suggesting the different series were not competing with each other for viewers.

Comment: @Izkata The seasonal pattern in TV viewing is related to the weather and daylight - more people stay inside during the winter months (see this study: http://www.galileoco.com/literature/seasonalTVBarnett91.pdf). I'm not sure why the seasonal oscillations flattened out for *DS9*, *Voyager*, and *Enterprise*.

Comment: +1 for a good answer, but those curves make me sad. DS9 seasons 3-5 deserved way better.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor: Great answer, please see my comment to Richard.

Comment: @sfhq_sf Thanks! I'm fine with you giving the tick to Richard; he got there first and included TOS. I wasn't expecting my answer to score so highly.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: Great answers with >3.5K views, I'm blown away.